# Get Left Join after group By And Count

Tags: mysql, sql

i have this Query

```
select device.device_id, device.device_category, count(device.device_category) referrals
from device
left join device_category  on device.device_category = device_category.cat_id
GROUP BY device.device_category


device_id| device_category| referrals
:------  | :---------     | --------:
    1    |     1          |      80
    3    |     5          |      7
```

but i dont get the left join from the device_category table
what is wrong with this query?

i wold like to get this result

```
  device_id  | device_category  | referrals  | cat_id   | cat_name
    :------  | :---------       | --------:  | --------:| --------:
        1    |     1            |      80    |     1    |     Video
        3    |     5            |      7     |     5    |     Audio
```

Comment: You need to select the columns you want in the `select`.  Also, your `select` columns are inconsistent with the `group by` columns, and the query *should* return an error -- even if older versions of MySQL allow this syntax.

Comment: OHHHH! Grate Thank U!!

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you want something like this:

```
select dc.*,
       (select count(*)
        from device d
        where d.device_category = dc.cat_id
       ) as num_referrals
from device_category dc;
```

Note:  This does not return `device_id`, because that column does not make sense in the aggregated results.

Comment: is there a way i can group before i count the  device_id from the device table?

Comment: @DrorShalit . . . That doesn't make sense.  Are you saying this doesn't do what you want (which appears to be counting rows in `device` for each category)?